# Subtract values from a DropDownList

Tags: sql

I've been stumped with some SQL as following

I've get two dropdownlist and let user to select Date, and here is the SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM [CountTable] WHERE (([Date] = @Date) OR ([Date] = @Date2))
```

And result:

```
Date        UserID  Count
18/12/2013  User1   100
19/12/2013  User1   105
19/12/2013  User2   10
```

And now, I want to have a SQL command to calculate the Count between two Date.
If the UserID is the same, then the new Count subtract the old Count.
If the UserID cannot be found in the old Date, then it remains the new Count.

The result that I want should be as follow:

```
UserID   Counter
User1    5
User2    10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to subtract the `@Date` record from the `@Date2` record, you can do the following:

```
SELECT 
  UserID,
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN [DATE] = @Date2 THEN Count
      ELSE -1*Count
    END
   ) AS Counter
FROM [CountTable]
WHERE (([Date] = @Date) OR ([Date] = @Date2))
GROUP BY UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work regardless of whether date1 comes before or after date2 (and vice versa):

```
select userid,
       sum(case
             when [ Date ] = @Date2 and @Date2 > @Date1 then
              [ Count ]
             when [ Date ] = @Date2 and @Date2 < @Date1 then
              - [ Count ]
             when [ Date ] = @Date1 and @Date1 > @Date2 then
              [ Count ]
             when [ Date ] = @Date1 and @Date1 < @Date2 then
              - [ Count ]
           end) as counter
  from [ CountTable ]
 where (([ Date ] = @Date) OR ([ Date ] = @Date2))
 group by userid
```